# Programmatically collapse a group row in NSOutlineView

Tags: swift2, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView with an action (see code) that collapse a row when the user clicks anywhere on that row. However it is not working for group.

Some rows are defined as group via the "shouldShowOutlineCellForItem" delegate method.

I can expand a group row programmatically, but not collapse it.  Any suggestions?
isExpanded is correctly set via the notifications.

```
@IBAction func didClick(sender: AnyObject?)
{
    assert(self.root != nil)
    let selectedRow = outlineView.clickedRow
    let proposedItem = (selectedRow == -1) ? self.root! : outlineView.itemAtRow(selectedRow) as! thOutlineNode

    if proposedItem.isExpanded
    {
        self.outlineView.collapseItem(proposedItem)
    }
    else
    {
        self.outlineView.expandItem(proposedItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made certain that you do enter the if clause for collapse, i.e. by `print("entered")`? You mentioned isExpanded is correctly set, but just to make sure, before pursuing what other sources of this not working there might be.

Comment: Yes, I stepped through it with the debugger. I also made sure that I have the correct item.

Comment: I even tried to dispatch it on the main queue (delayed action), but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly duplicate. Based on [this existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181792/nsoutlineview-doesnt-collapse-item) covering Objective-C, try adding the `NSOutlineViewDelegate` delegate method

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, shouldShowOutlineCellForItem item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

to the view controller of your `NSOutlineView`. From the Apple documentation for the `NSOutlineViewDelegate`, we see that this is expected behaviour:

> optional func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView,
>   shouldShowOutlineCellForItem item: AnyObject) -> Bool
>
> ...
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Returning NO causes frameOfOutlineCellAtRow: to return NSZeroRect,
>   hiding the cell. In addition, the row **will not be collapsible by
>   keyboard shortcuts**.

Comment: I am returning false in that function to hide the triangle. But if set to true, then yes it works. So now the issue becomes: how to hide the triangle while still allowing collapse?

Comment: From what I've read, it seems like this is by design (weird?). One possible way for you would be to overload the `outlineView(...)` method above with one that contains in essence the same content except for some proper modification w.r.t. .collapseItem. Overloading existing type delegates is a bit hmm though, so maybe there's another workaround.